# Solr boost query

Tags: solr

i'm using solr 4.o and having issue in boosting query

example

```
responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":38,
    "params":{
      "lowercaseOperators":"true",
      "disableCoord":"false",
      "bq":["(product_detail_status:1)^10",
        "(catalog_paid_status:6)^0.1",
        "(catalog_paid_status:5)^0.1",
        "(catalog_paid_status:4)^0.1",
        "(catalog_paid_status:3)^0.1",
        "(catalog_paid_status:2)^0.1",
        "(catalog_paid_status:0)^0"],
      "debugQuery":"true",
      "fl":"product_name,score,atalog_paid_status,product_detail_status,catalog_paid_status,member_id,member_classified_slno,member_classified_slno",
      "indent":"true",
      "q":"product_name Barley Seeds)",
      "qs":"30",
      "stopwords":"true",
      "wt":"json",
      "ps":"0",
      "defType":"edismax",
      "rows":"150"}},
```

in above response header catalog_paid_status=4 is coming down the catalog_paid_status=3 all the records have same value for the product name the only difference is that number of results of catalog_paid_status=4 is more than catalog_paid_status=3.

Please help in sorting out this problem.

Comment: If you want to boost records that have catalog_paid_status:4 over other statuses, then you need to give it a higher boost than the other statuses. For example, you could try (catalog_paid_status:4)^2.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. But the problem is yet not sort out. My concern is if catalog_paid_status=3 record is more than all the catalog_paid_status means 1,2,4,5,6 then what i should do. How boosting is working if any catalog_paid_status number of record is more than it is not working properly. So how i can dynamically boost the any catalog_paid_status. As you suggested to  do (catalog_paid_status:4)^2 but what if catalog_paid_status:3 record is more than catalog_paid_status:4. Please help.

Comment: So are you trying to boost catalog_paid_status according to how many records have that status? For example, if more records have catalog_paid_status=2, you then want to boost parts with catalog_paid_status=2?